# AES mcrypt_encrypt key size

Tags: php, encryption, aes, mcrypt

```
256 bit  = 256/8 = 32
192 bit = 192/8 = 24
128 bit = 128/8 = 16

<?PHP
include("AES.php"); // http://aesencryption.net/
    $string = "myawesometext to encrypt!";
    $key = "1234567890123456789012345";
    $block = 256;
    $aes = new AES($string, $key, $block);
    $enc = $aes->encrypt();
    $aes->setData($enc);
    $dec= $aes->decrypt();
    echo "After encryption: ".$enc."<br/>";
    echo "After decryption: ".$dec."<br/>";
?>
```

***Error: mcrypt_decrypt(): Key of size 25 not supported by this algorithm. Only keys of sizes 16, 24 or 32 supported***

When i use this site: http://aesencryption.net/
the encryption and decryption works perfectly.
*PHP: 5.6.3*

changing the key size is not really an option, seeing how this should be working.

Why am i using AES?
I am communicating between two servers (one being a third party) and the information being transferred in the communication could be a security leak if not encrypted. otherwise i would use a hashing. This data **needs** to be recoverable by a 3rd party with a key.

**IMPORTANT:**

- Current PHP version: 5.6.3 //does not work
- Last PHP version: 5.5.15//works

**----------------SOLVED**

version: 5.6.0
" **Invalid key and iv sizes are no longer accepted**. mcrypt_encrypt() will now throw a warning and return FALSE if the inputs are invalid. Previously keys and IVs were padded with '\0' bytes to the next valid size. " - http://php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-encrypt.php

Comment: What? i think you misunderstood.

Comment: I did not change my question at all, i just eradicated the code that is difficult to read, and changed the format. The question is Why wont my encryption decrypt despite it being able to be decrypted on the AESencyption.net website.

Comment: Please move your answer to the answer section and delete it from your question.

Answer (score 0):

use openssl_random_pseudo_bytes to generate your key. openssl_random_pseudo_bytes will generate bytes therefore you'll need to bin2hex to get an alphanumeric key. bin2hex will convert the bytes you have generated into an ASCII encoded hex.

```
//To generate a 16 bytes key use this: 
$key = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(8));
//24 bytes
$key = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(12));
//32 bytes
$key = bin2hex(openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16));
//To view the byte size:
echo "key byte size: ".strlen($key)."<br/>";
```